# How to retrieve z-index of the forms in Winfors (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, z-index, z-order

I am developing an application using Winforms (C#). I am creating mutiple instances of the same form ad then store their position and size and so on. The only thing I'm lacking is to save their z-index and then restore them to re-create the previously open windows. I appreciate your help in advance. Here is some code example: First I go through the open windows and by updating a counter i store a custom object in an XML file. This custom object has fields that correspond to different properties of a window such as position, background color, size, location and so on. Afterwards I read from the XML file to re-create the custom object and do the following:

```
            main.Size = note.Size;
            main.Location = note.Location;
            main.richTextArea.Text = note.UserInputText;
            main.richTextArea.BackColor = note.BackgroundColor;
            main.WindowState = (FormWindowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(FormWindowState), note.WindowState);
            main.Controls.SetChildIndex (main.richTextArea ,note.Z_Order.Value);
```

Note I don't want the z-index of the children of the form. I'd like to have the z-index of the main form that contains the children.

Comment: What have you tried? post some code that demonstrates effort to resolve the problem yourself, update your question with an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Whenever the user closes a window i store the z-index by going through the open windows and storew a z-index which is in an object I created by a counter:
`Z_Order = counter++`
Then I retrieve the stored object from an XML file and do the following:
`main.Controls.SetChildIndex (main.richTextArea ,note.Z_Order.Value);`

Comment: From reading the text I understand that you want to save and restore the z-index of `Form`s, but the code you share seems to restore the z-index of a `Control` instead. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To restore windows z-order, one can use the BringToFront or SendToBack Methods. For saving the Z-order, get it by calling the **GetWindow** function of **user32.dll**. Do a first call to get TopWindow (GW_HWNDFIRST = 0) then loop on nextwindow (GW_HWNDNEXT = 2). Identify the windows and eliminate those not belonging to your app.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis tnx for your reply. You are right i want the z-index of the form. I tried to use the code i showed but it didnt work.

Comment: @Graffito I tried your suggestion, bit for some reason I cannot retireve the z-index. But tnx anyhow :)

Comment: The Getwindow function provides the windows according to z-index: First is topmost and last is bottommost.

Comment: @Graffito I tried the GetWindow function and i still cannot retrive the forms in the correct order. Forms are returned in the order they were created. This happens when the user presses ctrl + N and them i create a new instance of the form.

Comment: When you read [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the z-order should be provided. Perhaps, calling EnumChildWindows will work ?

Comment: @Graffito I tried it and so many other things. They wouldnt work sadly. I guess my problem is i create a new window from within the application and try to stop the OnLoad and Oncreate based on certain conditions. I will simplify my app. Thanks for the help though. I really appreciate it.